# Как использовать WHERE при объединении двух запросов?

Tags: sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT t1.val, t2.val2 FROM dungeons,locations
```

Как тут поставить условие `WHERE`, чтобы с первой таблицы выбирать одно, а со второй другое.
Например я хочу с первой выбрать

```
WHERE rating > 100
```

а со второй

```
WHERE money=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.val, t2.val2 
  FROM dungeons t1,locations t2
 WHERE t1.rating > 100 and t2.money=0
```

Comment: Работает, но почему-то только после второго обновления браузера. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: @Erepaha вы до этого ничего не говорили о браузере

Comment: ну а вот теперь сказал )

Comment: А по подробнее про браузер, пожалуйста

Comment: отправляю вообщем этот запрос, сразу после него смотрю через var_dump(), возвращает NULL, обновляю страницу в браузере все работает. Но мне это не подходит :(

Comment: Я вот ничего не понял. Я понятия не имею, что такое var_dump(). О проблеме с обновлением страницы ничего сказать не могу, с ПХП я не в ладах

Comment: Если мой ответ отвечает на Ваш вопрос, примите его как верный. Если нет, то попробуйте переформулировать вопрос

Comment: @Erepaha Вопросы должны быть атомарными (то есть конкретными), если вы хотите что-то ещё спросить по теме не относящейся к `sql` задайте ещё один вопрос.